# border-box + padding + max-width = jumping elements?

Tags: css

Please have a look at these two fiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fw4dg/2/embedded/result/

```
<style>
    .outer, .inner {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box; }

    .outer {
        max-width: 600px;
        border: 1px solid #0f0;
        padding: 40px 10%; }

    .inner {
        border: 1px solid #f00; }
</style>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Watch the parent element's padding change when you narrow the viewport.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you narrow the window past the edges of the exterior box, that box's horizontal padding suddenly shrinks, and remains at its new width even after widening the window again (WebKit and Gecko).

http://jsfiddle.net/Fw4dg/1/embedded/result/

In another example, the second floated element clears the first floated element after the window is narrowed and widened again (WebKit only):

http://jsfiddle.net/Fw4dg/1/embedded/result/

This behavior is in both WebKit (tested in Safari 6.0.5 and Chrome 29.0.1547.49 beta) and Gecko (tested in Firefox 23 beta 10). It happens with or without the borders.

If you narrow and widen the window repeatedly, you can get some pretty strange effects in Safari:

[image: Safari broken CSS rendering: max-width, border-box, and padding]

The closest bug report to this that I could find is in Bugzilla, but doesn't seem to be describing quite the same thing:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308801

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a solution, then it could there. Just add `display: table;` to your `.inner` element.

Comment: Here's a video of it not working:
http://f.cl.ly/items/2k462m1L3I3f0T3l3F1B/Untitled.mov

This is in Firefox.

Comment: WHAT'S THAT? PLACE AN IMAGE

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Place an image where?